# openssl_x509: JWT certificate from: p7b p12 [php7.3] [Maskinporten]

Tags: php, openssl, jwt, x509

**Goal: Create a JWT with x5c param in header as base64 encoded x509 certificate. On the Norwegian platform Maskinporten. *So I need to create a JKS keystore file containing the certificate with the public + private keys***

Header in the JWT consists of 2 parts where alg must be 'RS256' (Only RSA-SHA256 is supported by Maskinporten) and x5c is set to Business Certificate (eSeal) for the organization. (Full certificate chain see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517#section-4.7) on PHP 7.3 platform. Signing with a business certificate is carried out with the private part (private/public) of the certificate.

I have received the following files (along with an Activation code):

```
auth-certificate.p12, sign-certificate.p12, auth-privatekeys.p7b, signing-privatekeys.p7b, public_keys.txt
```

- openssl_x509_parse on the 3 certificates in the public_keys.txt, but returns false
- openssl_x509_read isn't reading any of the certificates, only returns blank
- openssl_x509_fingerprint returns blank
- openssl_x509_verify is only available from PHP 7.4, but I recon this isn't working either

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** I used the following library: https://github.com/difi/jwt-grant-generator to generate a JWT from the Business certificate keystore file, and calling the executable JAR in the PHP Script.